# Finding printer names, driver and ip addresses off backup image

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-printer, shared-printers

I just installed a fresh copy of server 2003 and I totally forgot to write down all the ip addresses and printer names to re add them to the new server. I was in a rush due to getting nail with that fedex virus.

I have a copy of one of the last back ups that I can mount on an old machine. Is there anyway to look for the ip address,names or even something I can use to copy this information to my clean server?

Even just beable to get into a directory and writing all the info down would save me hours

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that I can think of that you can do this:

1. Restore the backup to a disconnected machine. Log on to the restored server and get the information.
2. Pull the registry files from the backup, mount/open the HKLM hive, navigate to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers and get the information from there.